# How to implement multiple cordova webviews in an Activity using fragments?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-fragments

I’m trying to build an android app using phonegap with several Cordova webviews. Now in order to do that, I’ve tried to create a FragmentActivity that implements CordovaInterface. However, the Cordova webviews in the fragments are losing their state whenever I switch between the fragments or as soon as there is a configuration change on android.

To switch between fragments, I’m using:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(container, frag)
      .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit();
```

where `container` is the fragment container and `frag` is my Cordova webview fragment

Any idea why the `replace` function is not saving the state of the current Cordova webview?

Comment: this question is kind of similar, i believe it will really help you Save & restoring WebView in an embedded PhoneGap app